# Why does a float print out as negative zero?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, math, matrix, transform

## Problem

Sometimes the floating point number of value zero is being printed out as negative zero even though inequality checks show that the number is non-negative.

## Application

I'm trying to log out the transformation matrix of a UIView in a human readable format. The numbers should be arranged like this:

[image]

```
- (void) describe
{
    NSLog(
        @"|%@%.2f %@%.2f 0.00|\n|%@%.2f %@%.2f 0.00|\n|%@%.2f %@%.2f 1.00|",
        self.transform.a < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.a,
        self.transform.b < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.b,
        self.transform.c < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.c,
        self.transform.d < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.d,
        self.transform.tx < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.tx,
        self.transform.ty < 0 ? @"" : @" ",
        self.transform.ty
    );
}
```

I place spaces in front of numbers that are non-negative to match the width of negative numbers. In some cases, the numbers line up:

```
| 0.00 -1.00 0.00|
| 1.00  0.00 0.00|
| 0.00  0.00 1.00|
```

After applying a few rotations to the view, the numbers don't line up anymore:

```
| -0.00 -1.00 0.00|
| 1.00  -0.00 0.00|
| 0.00  0.00 1.00|
```

In the above case, an `NSLog` of `self` prints out the transform as:

```
transform = [-0, -1, 1, -0, 0, 0];
```

The problem is zero values are logged out as negative zero, but being detected as non-negative. If I can understand how this mythical negative zero can even exist, then I can solve my formatting problem.

Comment: Negative zero is non-negative; it's zero. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero But why don't you just use field formatting instead of doing it such a hard way? For example:  `NSLog(
        @"|%5.2f %5.2f 0.00|\n|%5.2f %5.2f 0.00|\n|%5.2f %5.2f 1.00| ...`

Comment: @CarlNorum heh you beat me by few seconds with this (+1)

Comment: floating point values have mantisa,exponent and sign separate so they are capable of storing `+0 ` and `-0` which is the same ... the sign is leftover from last operation with such value ...

Comment: @CarlNorum  I tried your way of formatting, but the "5" in front of the decimal just sets a maximum bound of digits to the left of the decimal. It will pad small numbers.

Comment: @Pwner, it sets the field width for the whole number, not just left of the decimal. And what's wrong with padding? You want the numbers to line up, right?

Comment: @CarlNorum , I had a typo. I meant to say that I didn't see it pad small numbers like "1". It just appeared as "1.00" with no padding. Things didn't line up.

Comment: It should have; are you sure you put it in that way?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're deriving your values.  Are you sure that they're really zero and not -0.00000000000001?

Comment: @Spektre, my 2c is that your comment is useful as an answer.

Comment: @Pwner are you sure you are comparing to floating zero and not integer? on some compilers when you wrote `x < 0` instead of `x < 0.0f` then x is converted to integer type and compared as integer !!!

Comment: @Spektre There was no difference in the program when I used `x < 0.0f` instead of `x < 0`. Your first comment is a good explanation of what actually happened. You should submit it as an answer and I'll mark it. I almost forgot about the sign bit in front of floating point numbers because I hadn't used this knowledge since my college days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer moved from comment]

floating point values have mantisa,exponent and sign separate

- so they are capable of storing +0  and -0 which is the same ...
- the sign is leftover from last operation with such value ...